# Why the time complexity is different even when I am using only one loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, time-complexity

I am solving a question on CodeLab that asks to remove the duplicates in place such that each element can appear at most twice and return the new length.

Given input array A = [1,1,1,2]
Your function should return length = 3, and A is now [1,1,2]

My Python code is running fine and it is correct but it says the running time (time complexity) is too long. But when I run the Java code which is similar (one loop) it accepts it. What am I doing wrong in the Python code so that the time is way too much ?

```
def removeDuplicates(A):
    if len(A) <= 2:
        return len(A)
    i = 0
    n = len(A)
    while i < n:
        if i <= len(A)-3:
            if A[i] == A[i+1] and A[i] == A[i+2]:
                del A[i]
                i -= 1
        i += 1
    return i
```

Java Code:

```
public int removeDuplicates(ArrayList<Integer> a) {
    int count = 1;
    int shiftLeft = 0;
    int i = 1;
    while (i < a.size()){
        a.set(i-shiftLeft, a.get(i));
        if (a.get(i-1-shiftLeft).equals(a.get(i))){
            count ++;
        }
        else {
            count = 1;
        }
        if (count == 3){
            shiftLeft ++;
            count --;
        }
        i ++;
    }
    for (int j=0; j<shiftLeft; j++){
        a.remove(a.size()-1);
    }
    return a.size();
}
```

Comment: Please fix the python formatting. Indentation is more important there than in Java

Comment: Just guessing: `del A[i]` has complexity O(n-i). In Java you only call `a.remove(a.size()-1)` to remove the last element. (approx. O(1)).

Comment: I don't see how the python code works. You don't recalc `n` in the loop. This would surely throw index errors?

Comment: @MichaelButscher Thank you Michael. But since the pointer at index (i), does it still takes O(n-1) ?

Comment: `del A[i]` must shift all list elements from one after `i` to the end one index backward. In Python these elements are pointers (aka references) only, but the complexity is linear nevertheless.

Comment: Thank you @MichaelButscher But in this case is there anything that would help to do this in Python without del ?

Comment: Use the Java approach: Assign  `A[i - leftShift] = A[i]` if value shouldn't be deleted (otherwise just increase `leftShift` and `i`. Finally call `del` to remove the superfluous items at the end at once (`del [-leftShift:]` if `leftShift` isn't 0).

Answer (score 1):

Deleting from an array given an index takes linear time. That's because you must shift all elements to the right of it one space to the left, which takes O(n) as well.

You can do the deletion itself in constant time by using th following trick. First swap the element you want to delete to the end of the array, then reduce the array size by one element using `pop()`.

You couldn't implement a general purpose delete like that though because even though the array is not sorted, it still might have some particular order to it that needs to be preserved.

---

Back to the problem: you're given the constraint that you have to implement it in-place, with no additional space, and only one loop. That said, this is the best I can come up with now:

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6]

def removeDuplicates(l):
    for i in range(len(l) - 1, 0, -1): 
        if (l[:i]).count(l[i]) >= 2:
            del l[i]
    return(l)

print(removeDuplicates(A)) #=> 8
print(l) #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6]
```

Comment: Thank you. That is a good trick. But what if I want to delete more than one (say 4 or 5 elements) then how to keep swapping all of them ? Would you provide a small piece of code please

Comment: Are you allowed to use `set()`?

Comment: Set() will remove all the duplicates. I should allow at most 2 of each duplicates.

Comment: @anyanya use a `dict` of counts

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I have to do this in place without any additional space with only one loop